# Why does my dbms_output.put('AAA'); line not printing anything...?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
   i number(1);
   j number(1);
BEGIN
   << outer_loop >>
   FOR i IN 1..2 LOOP
      << inner_loop >>
      FOR j IN 1..i LOOP
         dbms_output.put('AAA');
      END loop inner_loop;
   END loop outer_loop;
END;
/
```

I have the code above .. but its not printing 'AAA' .. 
it works fine if i do dbms_output.put_line('AAA');

but i want to be able to print it on one line..

Why isn't dbms_output.put('AAA'); not working?..

Comment: Are you using `sqlplus` or some IDE like SQL Developer, Toad, etc?

Comment: @Munir I am using TOAD ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you want to print in one line, you´ll need a final `dbms_out.put_line` which will "flush" the output.
If you don´t, you won´t see anything ...

Comment: I see. I didn't know that. Thanks so much! I added that one line with put_line at the end and it works as expected now! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @oratom whilst `dbms_out.put_line` will work, technically, it's `dbms_out.new_line` that is required when working with `dbms_out.put`, as per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i1000105): `If you make calls to PUT to build a line, then you must add your own end-of-line marker by calling NEW_LINE`